# Controlling if download is successful from s3 to user

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using s3 to allow users to download files directly from frontend a limited number of times.

Problem is I need to know if a download was successful before I update the number of download left.

Is there any way I can get any kind of control over it like s3 callback when download finished or something?

The only thing I found was [Server Access Logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) but after reading trough the
Best Effort Server Log Delivery section I think I need something a bit more deterministic than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this capability is not possible. It is not possible to receive a notification when an object has been accessed. The logs are the only indication of activity.

If this is a vital need, then you will need to serve the file via your own application.